# In C# Webclient class output

Tags: c#

In C# console application , i need to capture the out "Internet cannot display the webpage", then i can put my check. If internet browser opens the url means internet connection is there, else connection down. I am using below code

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string value = client.DownloadString("http://foo.com");
        Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");

        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Please se the method to capture the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string value;

try
{
    value = client.DownloadString("http://foo.com");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    value = ex.Message;
}

Console.WriteLine(value.Length);
Console.WriteLine(value);
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: Note that you can get more information about the failed request from the exception. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I am trying to calculate the length , so length for Internet explorer cannot diplay the page is always 66 so i will using check for this. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the status code from web client.

Based on the status code you can identify the state of the current connection.

Please refer the following code.

[How to get status code from webclient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574659/how-to-get-status-code-from-webclient)